# Partial Matching in Java Regular Expression

Tags: java

I wrote the following code to match whole numbers only. However, when a decimal number like 3.4 is given it matches with the number 3. Is there any way to match the whole string and otherwise reject if a number is not whole number like 3.4?

```
Pattern e = Pattern.compile([0-9]+);
Matcher m = e.matcher("3.4");
```

Comment: [OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396285#comment66118776_39396366) in answer by baao: *I wanted to match only whole numbers*. This seems to contradict the sample code in the question, but it just means that the question is very poorly formulated. Beware!

Comment: How do you know it matches when you haven't called `m.matches()` yet?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's not calling m.matches(). Maybe OP's using find() or group()?

Comment: @Jeutnarg *My* guess is that OP thinks a non-null `m` means it matches. --- Couldn't be `group()`, because that would throw `IllegalStateException` if `matches()` or `find()` hasn't been called.

Comment: Oh, I was using m.find(). Thanks @Jeutnarg

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html should help

Comment: @Michael If you want to use `find()`, you need to add anchors: `"^[0-9]+$"`. In your case, I'd suggest you use `matches()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very confusing, but you may want to use the following to match numbers with or without decimals

```
Pattern e = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?");
```

Comment: @Andreas you're right - thank you, edited in my answer - hope it's okay for you.

Comment: @baao Thanks for the answer. But I wanted to match only whole numbers.